# Set installation prefix automatically to custom path if not explicitly specified on the command line

Tags: installation, cmake, prefix

For some internal tests, I would like the install prefix to default to a subdirectory of the build directory, unless explicitly overridden by the user. I know the user can specify a install prefix by:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/foo/bar ..
```

But if the user does *not* specify this, it should default to, e.g. `${PWD}/installed`.

The variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is already set to `/usr/local`, so I cannot just check to see if it unset/empty before setting it.

My current solution is to add a custom switch that the user has to invoke to specify that the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable gets respected:

```
option(ENABLE_INSTALL_PREFIX "Install build targets to system (path given by '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX' or '${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}' if not specified)." OFF)
if ( ENABLE_INSTALL_PREFIX )
    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX installed CACHE PATH "Installation root")
else()
    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX installed CACHE PATH "Installation root" FORCE)
endif()
```

My questions are:

(a) Are there any issues with the above, beyond the annoyance of the extra flag needing to be passed to CMake to get `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to have an effect?

(b) Is there a better, cleaner, more robust, more idiomatic and/or less annoying way to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

CMake sets the boolean variable [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT.html) if `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` has not been explicitly specified and is initialized to its default setting. You can override it in the following way:

```
if (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/installed"
           CACHE PATH "default install path" FORCE)
endif()
```

Comment: I wish I found this post a few days ago while I was pulling my hair out trying to get multiple ExternalProject dependencies to do the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, I wanted to attempt the same thing. Unfortunately I could never find a fully satisfactory solution. Instead, I chose to use a regex to check if `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` matches the default.

E.g. on windows I use the following to create the `install` dir in the build-directory:

```
if ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX MATCHES "^C:/Program Files" )
    # Override to an "Install" directory in the current build-dir
    message( STATUS "    Install-prefix was at default -> forcing it to the build-dir" )
    message( STATUS "        'set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install )'" )
    set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install )
endif ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX MATCHES "^C:/Program Files" )
```

The biggest problem with this construct is that you can specify manually that CMake should install into `C:\Program Files`. As I distribute my tool with an NSIS-installer this is not an issue (for me).

Perhaps you could try something similar on Unix.

Comment: On Unix one would use `"^/usr/local"` in the matching; or, even better, `STREQUAL "/usr/local"` instead of a regular expression matching.